# free tool to create feature wireframes on an existing site

Tags: user-experience, wireframe, mockups

I want to create mockups of new features for an existing site. I'm looking for a simple, free, tool to help em do that. I'm not a gui designer, so I'm not looking for something that keeps the same look and feel, or that is pixel perfect, it can be just a wireframe. Better if it allows the mockups to be click-through (and any other interactive features)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use [Pencil](http://pencil.evolus.vn/) for making mockups. It's free, open source, and cross-platform, and has a good variety of mockup widgets available. It looks like there are some web widgets available (assuming "existing site" refers to a website), there are plenty of desktop widgets, and there are basic rectangles, arrows, polygons, etc. for simple wireframes too. You won't find much in the way of interactivity, but that hasn't been a huge issue for me so far.